# Java 8 Map default implementation details

Tags: java, java-8

I went through the default implementation of the new Java 8 Map methods like `getOrDefault` and noticed something slightly weird. Consider for example the `getOrDefault` method. It is implemented as follows.

```
default V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
    V v;
    return ((v = get(key)) != null) || containsKey(key) ? v : defaultValue;
}
```

Now, the "weird" thing here is the "Result of assignment used" pattern in `((v = get(key)) != null`. To my knowledge, this particular pattern is discouraged, since it rather obstructs readability. An IMO more concise version would be something along the lines of

```
default V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
    V v = get(key);
    return v != null || containsKey(key) ? v : defaultValue;
}
```

My question is if there is any particular reason to use the former over the latter pattern aside from coding standards / habits. In particular, I wonder if these two versions are trace and performance equivalent?

The only thing I could imagine is that the compiler might e.g. determine that `containsKey` is usually faster to evaluate and thus evaluates it first, but as far as I know short-circuiting has to preserve order of execution (this is the case for C at least).

EDIT: Following @ruakh suggestion, here are the two bytecodes (as generated by `javap -c`)

```
  public V getOrDefault(java.lang.Object, V);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokeinterface #1,  2            // InterfaceMethod get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
       7: dup                               // <-- difference here
       8: astore_3
       9: ifnonnull     22
      12: aload_0
      13: aload_1
      14: invokeinterface #2,  2            // InterfaceMethod containsKey:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      19: ifeq          26
      22: aload_3
      23: goto          27
      26: aload_2
      27: areturn
```

and

```
  public V getOrDefault(java.lang.Object, V);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokeinterface #1,  2            // InterfaceMethod get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
       7: astore_3
       8: aload_3                           // <-- difference here
       9: ifnonnull     22
      12: aload_0
      13: aload_1
      14: invokeinterface #2,  2            // InterfaceMethod containsKey:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      19: ifeq          26
      22: aload_3
      23: goto          27
      26: aload_2
      27: areturn
```

I have to admit that even after years and years of Java coding I have no idea how to interpret Java bytecode. Could someone kindly shed some light on the difference here?

Comment: I don't know what the answer *is*, but it's definitely *not* about the compiler calling `containsKey`, for a bunch of reasons, including the one you mention, and including that the method is actually carefully written to *avoid* calling `containsKey` unless necessary.

Comment: I suspect, by the way, that the two versions actually compile to the same bytecode. (You can easily test that.) If so, then there can't be any technical reason.

Comment: Commenting on your second point: Definitely, this was the design choice for the short-circuit order (only call `containsKey` when v turns out to be `null`), which is the optimal choice **in general**. The advantage of an JIT compiler is that it can adapt to specific situations. But then again, as you confirm, there are other reasons which should prohibit this kind of "optimization".

Comment: @ruakh I don't think so. The JDK version should have `... DUP ASTORE_2 IFNULL ...` while OP's version use `... ASTORE_2 ALOAD_2 IFNULL ...`. I'm not sure if stack is faster than local variables and I didn't actually tested that, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is only a style issue. Some people prefer the most compact code possible,
while others prefer longer but simpler code. It seems some of the developers
working on the Java core library belong to the former group.

In terms of efficiency, both variants are identical.

---

Let's have a look at what the compiler actually does with these two variants:

```
public class ExampleMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    V getOrDefault1(Object key, V defaultValue) {
        V v;
        return ((v = get(key)) != null) || containsKey(key) ? v : defaultValue;
    }

    V getOrDefault2(Object key, V defaultValue) {
        V v = get(key);
        return v != null || containsKey(key) ? v : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Now let's dump the generated bytecode, using `javap -c ExampleMap`:

```
Compiled from "ExampleMap.java"
public class ExampleMap<K, V> extends java.util.HashMap<K, V> {
  public ExampleMap();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/util/HashMap."<init>":()V
       4: return

  V getOrDefault1(java.lang.Object, V);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokevirtual #2                  // Method get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
       5: dup
       6: astore_3
       7: ifnonnull     18
      10: aload_0
      11: aload_1
      12: invokevirtual #3                  // Method containsKey:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      15: ifeq          22
      18: aload_3
      19: goto          23
      22: aload_2
      23: areturn

  V getOrDefault2(java.lang.Object, V);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokevirtual #2                  // Method get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
       5: astore_3
       6: aload_3
       7: ifnonnull     18
      10: aload_0
      11: aload_1
      12: invokevirtual #3                  // Method containsKey:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
      15: ifeq          22
      18: aload_3
      19: goto          23
      22: aload_2
      23: areturn
}
```

As you can see, the code is mostly identical. The only small difference is in lines
5 and 6 of both methods. One just duplicates the top value of the stack
(remember, Java bytecode assumes a stack-based machine model), while the other
loads the (identical) value from an instance variable.

When the Just-in-Time compiler generates real machine code out of this byte
code, it will perform various optimizations, like deciding which values to
write back to RAM and which to keep in CPU registers. I think it is safe to
assume that after these optimizations have happened, there is no difference
left whatsoever.

Comment: So, to summarize, these two implementations are equivalent in terms of observed behavior and probably are performance-equivalent, right?

Comment: @incaseoftrouble: yes.

Comment: While I am not sure about "In terms of efficiency, both variants are identical." I think we can agree that they are at least "almost identical" and the difference probably is so minor that it might vary between JVMs and executing platform. Accepting your answer.

Comment: HotSpot uses an [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) representation, which basically eliminates all transfers between and inside the stack and local variables. The only difference between these coding styles would apply if there were more than four variables, as `aload n` would take two bytes instead of the invariant one byte of `dup`. But even for verification or interpreted execution, it would be hard to measure a performance difference in that case.

Answer (score 3):

@ruakh has point out in comment that is `containsKey` method is not be invoked when `v` is not null that for performance purpose.

```
default V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
  V v;
  return ((v = get(key)) != null) || containsKey(key) ? v : defaultValue;
  //                                 ^-- short-circuit if get(key) != null.
}
```

the reason that [@Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175108/7607923) has pointed out in his answer.

Comment: But this is the case in the second version, too. Both of the `containsKey` calls are "guarded" by short-circuit.

Comment: @incaseoftrouble Hi, `dup` is faster than `astore_n`.

Comment: In general it may be but I guess we can't conclude that the actual execution will be different in this instance without extensive tests, since the compiler probably is able to translate both versions into the same machine code. I don't know how to verify this claim properly

Comment: @incaseoftrouble you can easily see `[before]-[after]` column from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings). that the `dup` instruction is faster.

Comment: This is a behavioral specification, not an implementation specification. A compiler might decide to do whatever as long as the observed behavior is conforming to what the specification dictates given the bytecode, similar to how a CPU is allowed a lot of freedom to interpret its instructions. Especially, this does not allow a rigorous conclusion about actual performance, only an (educated) guess.

Comment: @incaseoftrouble Not only the invocations but also the `target` they operates. `dup` only operates an operand stack but `astore_n` operates a local variables array & operand stack. you can see the JSL as I mentioned in my answer above in depth.

Comment: The JLS is a semantic specification, the java bytecode forms an ISA. Both alone do not allow any conclusion about actual performance, only guesses. They depend (among other things) on the executing JVM. To conclude anything like "x is faster than y (in this context, in reality)" actual benchmarks are mandatory, since compilers are awfully complex.

This discussion diverges from the original question, so we should refrain from continuing it.

Comment: I doubt that there will be a real performance difference, but who said that JRE developers are immune against falling for “felt performance”. This seems to be connected to the observed desire to write “one-liners”, except that the formal variable declaration can’t be inlined…

Comment: The question is about two variants to express the same operation. The one chosen for the JRE is more likely the result of a habit than a performance consideration.

Comment: @Holger Excuse me, sir. even if it is a programming habits, but I found I can clarify that why `dup` is faster than `astore_n`. Am I right?

Comment: @Holger I can off the record confirm that his is pure habit for *many* jdk devs, not sure if all. At a JUG that I attended I specifically asked this question from a russian speaking oracle-dev and the answer was "Doug Lea  and his friends to blame". I can't really tell if it was ironic

Comment: @holi-java No. You try to argue by abstract specification. Less or "conceptually simpler" (abstract) instructions do not necessarily imply that the execution is faster (consider e.g. loop unrolling). Practically all specifications only talk about observed behaviour. The compiler might for example inline some implementation (probably not this one though), which *completely* changes the abstract bytecode. For example, inlined methods don't have a separate stack frame. I would not be surprised if the JITC in the end runs the exact same machine instructions in our case. JMH benchmarks are needed.

Comment: @incaseoftrouble from the machine code, basically the `dup` instruction  allocate memory (1) & assignment (1). but the `astore_n` instruction that will aollocate memory(1) & assignment(1) & deallocate memory(1). which is faster?

Comment: @incaseoftrouble but the performance is not the reason that makes developer do that, maybe the reason @Eugene has pointed out in his answer. `dup` will result in less bytes code since its name is shorter than `astore_n`, ^_^.

Comment: @holi-java As I said multiple times: Java byte code is *not* machine code as in (executable) instructions. It's (highly) abstract byte code interpreted by the Java *virtual* machine. Between this format and actually executed machine code lie multiple layers of abstraction (similar to e.g. the difference between assembly and microcode). Just compile the code with GCJ and look at the differences. And yes, that this particular design was not done for performance reasons was concluded a long time ago (it was even suggested by the original question).

Comment: @holi-java: neither, `dup` nor `astore`, allocate memory. The required amount of stack space is fixed for every method at compile-time and recorded in the byte code. The stack frame, holding the space for every local variable and operand stack entry, is reserved on method entry and dropped at method exit.

Comment: @Holger thanks to point out my problem. `dup` is faster  than `astore_n`  since `astore_n` need to deallocate memory, Am I right?

Comment: No, none of these instructions will allocate or deallocated memory. As said, [stack frames are created when a method is entered and destroyed when the method is leaved](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6), but even that doesn’t imply memory allocation or deallocation, as in HotSpot each thread has a fixed size, preallocated memory for its stack.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest this has bothered me for quite a while too. And I found 3 *different*, but sort of similar scenarios to yours in the jdk sources. The first one is the one that you have asked about and got an answer so not going to say anything about it. The second one is slightly different:

```
 ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

 public void test(){
     ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;  
 }
```

This is need for *extreme* byte code optimization. You can test this, but it produces smaller byte-code in this case. And for a *core* library smaller means much better.

The third example is close to the previous one, but imagine that `lock` is `volatile`. Well, since volatile has *memory semantics* that are different than usual variables (it introduces memory barriers) that would give you a consistent value. Consistency in this case might mean more then *just* this variable, but all the values stored *before* the store to this particular volatile (it's how volatiles work...).

Comment: @holi-java it's probably in what you actually tested. It is absolutely generating less byte code/size. See here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-May/004164.html. Also there was a SO question about this a while ago with ArrayBlockingQueue` if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: thanks, I will see it immediately. Maybe your answer is a reason that why the developer write such a ugly code. reduce a bit little at a time, then can reduce a huge little in library.

Comment: @holi-java *ugly* in your opinion... *readability* is a personal thing, especially when it provides actual value/optimizations.

Comment: Even if `lock` is not declared `volatile`, a field read bears the possibility that the field has changed in-between the reads, hence, requires the generated code to re-fetch the value from RAM. That’s especially relevant here, as the code will do `lock` and `unlock` operations, having an impact on the memory visibility. In contrast, if you use a local variable, it is impossible that the reference gets changed by another thread. Even if the code calls methods which have not been inlined, it’s clear that these can not change the local variable…

Comment: @Holger so you are saying that in-between reads *even* a volatile variable can change? (sorry, it is sometimes hard to get you). If so, than yes, I do agree. My point was that once you read a volatile, all variables that were written *before* the write to the same variable are now visible to this thread. That is sometimes referred as "piggy-backing".

Comment: @Holger also that re-read is rarely a read from RAM AFAIK. There's a `StoreLoad` before a volatile read, that  actually drains the buffer into the `L1` cache - so it's up to cache coherency protocol to sync the data everywhere.

Comment: Ok, let’s replace “RAM” with “shared memory” to avoid such technical details. It should be clear that reading a `volatile` variable may enforce re-reading all other shared variables too. But *even* if the variable is *not* `volatile`, there’s an enforced re-reading due to “piggy-backing” on the `lock()` operation, typically happening between the two read operations. The only way to avoid this re-reading of `lock` is to a) declare `lock` as `final` or b) store the result of the first read into a local variable, which is what your answer is about.

Comment: Maybe, I should remind that if you don’t store the contents of `lock` into a local variable, you’ll have two reads, if you say `lock.lock(); … lock.unlock();`, which is, what my comment was about. Storing the contents of the field into a local variable and using the local variable for both operations guarantees that there will be only one read from the shared memory.

Comment: @Holger I think that this finally makes sense to me... I think that this is the reason of why `HashMap#keySet` is the way it is. `keySet` field used to be volatile and they removed volatile and do a single racy read there by copying the reference locally. This way they can drop the expensive volatile-implied barriers there and rely on the fact that `KeySet` has only final fields; thus providing safe publishing.